# Is there a way to return the attributes selected by an AttributeSelectedClassifier?

Tags: attributes, classification, weka

It would be useful to count the total number of times an AttributeSelectedClassifier had selected each attribute. I'm running different classification models on separate groups of data.

Besides doing something cumbersome like using toString to return a giant classifier description, from which to try to collect attribute names using StringUtils, is there a way to simply get the attributes the classifier has selected (or at least to get a string list of attributes that's shorter than the entire classifier)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The description of the `AttributeSelectedClassifier` is:

> Dimensionality of training and test data is reduced by attribute
>   selection before being passed on to a classifier.

So you can just run the attribute selection method yourself. The default method in the Explorer GUI is `CfsSubsetEval`. If you have changed to a different attribute selector,  run that.